# QueryDsl Query for JPA baesd on multiple filters and multiple tables

Tags: querydsl

I am new to querydsl and trying to get data from Postgres Using JPA and based on multiple fiters. I have tried using any() but it did not help. Tried another option with subquery but not sure how to handle multiple subquery within a query.

So i have a requirement where i want to filter data from different tables and based on multiple filters.

Company entity has a list of products it deals with(just a list, Product is not an entity)
So i have a company entity, Employee entity, Address Entity and Department Entity.

I want to fetch records from company entity based on following filter:
1. For a particular employee or list of employee AND
2. For employees from a particular country or from a list of countries AND
3. For employee from a particular department of list of department AND
4. For a particular product which is a list in company.

I want all of the above criteria to be used in querydsl as all these values will be coming out of values selected from UI Drop down filter.

Can anyone please help me in filtering this data using querydsl?